# split string using MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

split string using MYSQL query --

```
id      message       mobile                                status      
1       hello       9074739352                          DELIVERED
2       hi          9074739352,9074739353               DELIVERED,FAILED
3       Testing     9074739353                          DELIVERED
4       Sorav       9074739353,9074739354,9074739355    DELIVERED,FAILED,DELIVERED
5       good        9074739353                          DELIVERED
```

using this query -- `SELECT * FROM send_sms`

it get result like that --

```
array(
    [0] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'message' => 'hello',
            'mobile'  => '9074739352',
            'status'  => 'DELIVERED'
            ),
    [1] => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'message' => 'hi',
            'mobile'  => '9074739352,9074739353',
            'status'  => 'DELIVERED,FAILED'
            ),
    [2] => array(
            'id' => 3,
            'message' => 'Testing',
            'mobile'  => '9074739353',
            'status'  => 'DELIVERED'
            ),
    [3] => array(
            'id' => 4,
            'message' => 'Sorav',
            'mobile'  => '9074739353,9074739354,9074739355',
            'status'  => 'DELIVERED,FAILED,DELIVERED'
            ),
    [4] => array(
            'id' => 5,
            'message' => 'good',
            'mobile'  => '9074739353',
            'status'  => 'DELIVERED'
            )
)
```

but i want to result like that using MYSQL query --

```
array(
    [0] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'message' => 'hello',
            'mobile'  => '9074739352',
            'status'  => 'DELIVERED'
            ),
    [1] => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'message' => 'hi',
            'mobile'  => '9074739352',
            'status'  => 'DELIVERED'
            ),
    [2] => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'message' => 'hi',
            'mobile'  => '9074739353',
            'status'  => 'FAILED'
            ),
    [3] => array(
            'id' => 3,
            'message' => 'Testing',
            'mobile'  => '9074739353',
            'status'  => 'DELIVERED'
            ),
    [4] => array(
            'id' => 4,
            'message' => 'Sorav',
            'mobile'  => '9074739353',
            'status'  => 'DELIVERED'
            ),
    [5] => array(
            'id' => 4,
            'message' => 'Sorav',
            'mobile'  => '9074739354',
            'status'  => 'FAILED'
            ),
    [6] => array(
            'id' => 4,
            'message' => 'Sorav',
            'mobile'  => '9074739355',
            'status'  => 'DELIVERED'
            ),
    [7] => array(
            'id' => 5,
            'message' => 'good',
            'mobile'  => '9074739353',
            'status'  => 'DELIVERED'
            )
)
```

I want to solve this issue using MYSQL query.

Comment: The question is: "Why do you have multiple data in the same field?"

Comment: terrible database design. I suggest you start by converting your database into 3NF and then use normal queries without trying to figure out ridiculous solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SUBSTRING_INDEX** to do that

```
SELECT
  id,
  message,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(mobile,',',1) AS mobile,
  status
FROM send_sms;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB > select SUBSTRING_INDEX('9074739352,9074739353',',',1);
+------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('9074739352,9074739353',',',1) |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 9074739352                                     |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: can you tell me how can we do that without query ...can we do that using nested foreach loop ??

Comment: i am not understand why you not want to use a query. it is also not the best idea to store multiple data in one field. SO i cant answer this. I am not good  in php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow query for required outout,

```
select id,message,SUBSTRING_INDEX(mobile,",",1) as mobile,SUBSTRING_INDEX(status,",",1) as status from send_sms
union select id,message,substring_index(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mobile,",",2),',',-1) as mobile,substring_index(SUBSTRING_INDEX(status,",",2),',',-1) as status from send_sms
union select id,message,substring_index(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mobile,",",3),',',-1) as mobile,substring_index(SUBSTRING_INDEX(status,",",3),',',-1) as status from send_sms;
```

But it is not good practice to create database design like this.